# Change Date value from one TimeZone to another TimeZone

Tags: calendar, timezone, java, simpledateformat

my case is I have a Date obj the date inside is UTC time. However I want it to be changed to Japan time.

```
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Japan"));
    calendar.setTime(someExistingDateObj);
     System.out.println(String.valueOf(calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)) + ":" + calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
```

the existingDateObj is mapped from db and db value is 2013-02-14 03:37:00.733

04:37

it seems the timezone is not working?

thanks for your time....

Comment: What are you using ? `java.sql.Date` or `java.util.Date` ? As I've checked it for Utils object and its working fine.

Comment: Even in case of `java.sql.Date` it doesn't makes any difference. Working fine for me ! Can you post the code you are using for `someExistingDateObj`.

Comment: @dShringi  thanks for you reply Shringi. pls see my discussion with Ryan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem may be that you're looking at things wrong. A `Date` doesn't have a time zone. It represents a discrete moment in time and is ["intended to reflect coordinated universal time"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html). Calendars and date formatters are what get time zone information. Your second example with the Calendar and TimeZone instances appears to work fine. Right now, this code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Japan"));
    System.out.println(String.valueOf(calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR)) + ":" + calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
}
```

Reports:

```
0:32
```

That appears correct to me. What do you find wrong with it?

**Update:** Oh, perhaps you're expecting `12:32` from the above code? You'd want to use [Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#HOUR_OF_DAY) instead of [Calendar.HOUR](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#HOUR) for that, or else do some hour math. Calendar.HOUR uses 0 to represent both noon and midnight.

**Update 2:** Here's my final attempt to try to get this across. Try this code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("H:mm a Z");
    List<TimeZone> zones = Arrays.asList(
            TimeZone.getTimeZone("CST"),
            TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"),
            TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Shanghai"),
            TimeZone.getTimeZone("Japan"));
    for (TimeZone zone : zones) {
        calendar.setTimeZone(zone);
        format.setTimeZone(zone);
        System.out.println(
                calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) + ":"
                + calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE) + " "
                + (calendar.get(Calendar.AM_PM) == 0 ? "AM " : "PM ")
                + (calendar.get(Calendar.ZONE_OFFSET) / 1000 / 60 / 60));
        System.out.println(format.format(calendar.getTime()));
    }
}
```

Note that it creates a single Calendar object, representing "right now". Then it prints out the time represented by that calendar in four different time zones, using both the Calendar.get() method and a SimpleDateFormat to show that you get the same result both ways. The output of that right now is:

```
22:59 PM -6
22:59 PM -0600
4:59 AM 0
4:59 AM +0000
12:59 PM 8
12:59 PM +0800
13:59 PM 9
13:59 PM +0900
```

If you used Calendar.HOUR instead of Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, then you'd see this instead:

```
10:59 PM -6
22:59 PM -0600
4:59 AM 0
4:59 AM +0000
0:59 PM 8
12:59 PM +0800
1:59 PM 9
13:59 PM +0900
```

It correctly shows the current times in Central Standard Time (my time zone), UTC, Shanghai time, and Japan time, respectively, along with their time zone offsets. You can see that they all line up and have the correct offsets.

Comment: thanks for your quick reply . in the second case . Date toString is 2013-02-14 03:37:00  but String.valueOf(calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR)) + ":" + calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE)  is 4:37 which is not correct....

Comment: Nothing in your second case gives that date. Try out my code to prove that it works. You can check it against [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=current+japan+time). If you're still not convinced, try to provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org), and someone can point out where you're going wrong.

Comment: You also haven't mentioned what time zone you're in. Why is 4:37 not the correct output for 3:37 your time?

Comment: thanks Ryan, sorry for the confusion. I am in Shanghai and pls see my updated question...thanks again

Comment: @JobSmith `Date.toString()` always uses the system default time zone. And `Calendar` should be returning you correct value, according to the `TimeZone` you've used.

Comment: You're confusing yourself again by printing the value of `calendar.getTime()`, which returns a `Date`, which, again, has no time zone built in, so you're leaving it up to the formatter, which, as dShringi just pointed out, defaults to your local time zone. Use my code, and plug in your `someExistingDateObj`. You'll get the right answer.

Comment: @Ryan Stewart I am using your code and setTime(someExistingDateObj) and printout the value using calendar...the value is not correct.. this existingDate obj is from DB and value in the db is 3:57AM which is UTC time. and what i got after calendar is 4:57.....

Comment: I've updated my answer one more time. If you still think it's not working, you're going to have to provide a complete, executable example with expected input and output (an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)), like I mentioned earlier.

Comment: @Ryan Stewart thanks for your answer. it is absolutely right and really appreciate it. i just figure out my issue. i want to share with everyone. When I call setTime(existingDate), this existingDate is causing problem. because when this existingDate is generated it used my local time zone as default.so the timeoffset inside this existingDate is based on my timezone.However, what i thought is the offset inside this existingDate is based on UTC timing. so that's why the output is not the same as I expected..Yes.Calendar do the job. thanks everyone...

Comment: Actually, I see you've updated your question again to say that 04:37 isn't the correct output when the date in your time zone is 03:37. You're one hour behind Japan. How is that not correct?

Comment: @Ryan Stewart  hah, actually if I consider 03:37 as my local time, yes, 04:37 is correct. but 03:37 in my case is UTC time so 04:37 is not correct.....

Comment: @JobSmith Your `setTime(existingDate)` was giving you local time zone value as internally what it does is `setTimeInMillis(existingDate.getTime());` which again is a `Date` object giving you local time zone value. Hence giving you default value.

Answer (score 0):

sdf2 and sdf3 are equaly initialized, so there is no need for two of them.